# Double integrals question please?

Tags: integration

We have the double integral$$\int_{0}^{1} dx\int_{0}^{x} {f(x,y)}  dy$$
In my book it says that we change the order of the integral and we have 
$$\int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{y}^{1} {f(x,y)} dx$$

How is this even possible? Can you explain this to me?

Comment: I corrected it the right way I want it.

Comment: Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left\{\begin{aligned} 0\le x\color{red}{\le}1 \\ 
0\le y\color{green}{\le}  x \\ 
 \end{aligned} \right.\Rightarrow\left\{\begin{aligned} y\le x\le 1 \\ 
0\le y\color{green}{\le} x\color{red}{\le}1\to0\le y\color{red}{\le}1\\ 
 \end{aligned} \right.$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw the region of integration. You will see.